# how do I get AJAX to pass button click to python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I'm a novice.  I would like to pass a value from an HTML button click on the client's browser to a python script on the server to send a value to a PostgreSQL db.  I must be missing something.  Here's what the javascript, and AJAX in the HTML look like:

```
 <div class="note" id="(Untitled)">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.1.js">
$(function () {
    $("#one").click(function () {
        $("#one").trigger("click", ["1"]);
        do_it(1);
        });
    $("#two").click(function () {
        $("#two").trigger("click", ["2"]);
        do_it(2);
        });
});

function do_it(n) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "~/script_for_practice_jun20.py",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {param: 'n'}
    success: success
}),
}
)
```

Here's the python part that I am using...

```
    def cgi_get_from_ajax(self):
        import json
        import cgi
        data = cgi.FieldStorage()
        chosen = data["param"].value
        return chosen

    def set_choice(self):
        process = Name_of_class()
        choice = process.cgi_get_from_ajax()
        entry = []
        if choice == '1':
            entry = [1,0,]
        else:
            entry = [0,1]
        return entry
```

My deadline is approaching.  Please help me.  Please.  Please.

Comment: Homework/study? Either way: where are you stuck? Trace what's happening. Does the button click trigger the AJAX call? Does the AJAX call reach the Python server? If so, does the Python script attempt to communicate with the database? Each stage has useful tools (Firebug / chrome developer console; wireshark; print statements and web server logs; database server logs with `log_statement = all`). Use them.

Comment: Also, while I think his explanation is wrong, Maulik is probably correct in saying that `~/script_for_practice_jun20.py` is not the correct path for your script *as seen by the web server*. You need a relative or absolute URL that's valid for the client application here, not a server-side path.

Comment: Dear Craig, It is neither Homework nor Study.

Comment: Debug in the console shows no error in Firefox. I don't know how to see if the Ajax call is reaching the Python server.  The Python script works fine, and updates like a champ.Would I be looking in /var/logs/ on a webserver? It is apache on a large host. I do not know how to use 'log_statement = all' Where would I add this? Craig, thank you.

Comment: Craig, I don't think I can legally remote capture to the network.

Comment: Chrome's developer console (F12) is handy - check out the "Network" and javascript log/ console sections.

Comment: I added log_statement = all to the config file

Answer (score 0):

`url: "~/script_for_practice_jun20.py",`

this is a server friendly url. jquery cant use url with `~` sign.

**correct you url**, either relative to current page, or absolute from root directory.

**Did You Got Any Error In Console?**

Comment: Um, what? "Jquery can't use (a) url (a) with `~` sign". References/links? It's just another legal URL character. That said, I suspect you're right that the script isn't actually at that path as far as the web server is concerned.

Comment: @CraigRinger As far as I know, `~` sign is used to refer path from root system ditectory on server, how does jquery know that what is root directory on your server?

Comment: @CraigRinger  :  yes `~` is valid **but for server** , but how jquery can handle url starts with `~`?

Comment: I removed "~/" since the .py file is in the same directory as the HTML file